# Variable parameter type for virtual function in interface

Tags: c++, interface

I am currently wrapping access to different programming languages interpreters in a single interface as following.

```
class Interpreter
{

public:
    virtual int Evaluate(const stirng& cmd) = 0;
    virtual void SetInterpreter(void * interpeter) = 0;
};
```

I have function `SetInterpreter` to set an interpreter instance.
The issue that its parameter will vary according to the target interpreter.
`void *` will work as generic parameter , but I'l lose all type info about the passed parameter.

So is there any alternative providing some sort of type checking ?

---

### Edit 1 : usage example

```
Class TCLInterpreter : public Interpreter {

public:    

    void SetInterpreter(void* interpreter)
    {
    this->tcl_interpreter = (Tcl_Interp *) interpreter;
    }
};
```

I can't check the type of the parameter, so I can't guarantee the behavior if parameter of another type was passed .

Comment: A template class with the type of the interpreter?

Comment: your post is not very clear, but it seems to me like you want [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)?

Comment: A polymorphic interpreter?

Comment: you need to give a *for instance* of an intended use. It is not clear at all what `SetInterpreter` should do

Comment: What about `std::function`?

Comment: @jdehesa, Yes I may try that

Comment: @petersohn, badly I have to stick with c++98

Comment: what is `Tcl_Interp` and what types do you expect for `interpreter`? Because if they are related then a simple `dynamic_cast` would suffice.

Comment: @bolov `Tcl_Interp` is the c structure for `Tcl` interpreter, tcl is an interpreted language used for test automation ( or at least my case).

No interpreter are not related at all, it will change to totally different thing, if I added support for Python or ruby

Comment: Does `SetInterpreter(...)` need to be a part of the virtual interface?  Do you plan to call it on a base pointer? I'd assume you'd like to set the interpreter when instantiating the interpreter, where the concrete type is known, thus you can define `SetInterpreter(...)` in every concrete class with the concrete parameter type.

Comment: @nVxx, this is what I am currently exploring and I think it's more elegant and currently testing it.